# How to strip &_escaped_fragment_=?view=classic type parameters off of end of incoming url requests in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Google is appending the following parameters (among others) to the end of my search listings and my website cannot handle it and I need them stripped off by code in my .htaccess file:

```
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=classic
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=flipcard
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=magazine
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=mosaic
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=snapshot
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=timeslide
```

I have already received a response from @Croises to remove the other parameters they are adding and the current code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule (.+\.html?)$ $1? [NC,R=301,L]
```

How should I modify that code above to handle all the &_escaped_fragment_=?view=... parameters too?

@anubhava, is this what you want me to implement, with your code first in the list?  Thanks again!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)&_escaped_fragment_= /$1? [NC,NE,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-admin.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-content.*
RewriteRule (.+\.html?)$ $1? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you give example of full URL?

Comment: Yes, the url coming in is:
shareyourrepair.com/2012​/08​/how-to-put-patch-on-inner-tube.html&_escaped_fragment_=?view=flipcard

but I want it to come to: 
ShareYourRepair.com/2012​/08​/how-to-put-patch-on-inner-tube.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)&_escaped_fragment_= /$1? [NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried that code but it still doesn't work and I get the page not found error.  When I test the url I gave you above, this is what it turns it into (according to my log): /2012%E2%80%8B/08%E2%80%8B/how-to-put-patch-on-inner-tube.html&_escaped_fragm%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bent_=?view=flipcard

Comment: This is what I have
    `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-admin.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-content.*
   RewriteRule (.+\.html?)$ $1? [NC,R=301,L]`

for the redirection portion of it

Comment: sorry, I'm having a problem making it format the code like I want, with a new line for each line

Comment: Oh, I removed it after I tested it and it didn't work, this is what I was set to:
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-admin.*  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-content.*  
    RewriteRule (.+\.html?)$ $1? [NC,R=301,L]  
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=[^&]+ [NC]  
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)&_escaped_fragment_= /$1? [NC,NE,R=301,L]

Comment: I added what I think you now want me to implement in the original question, at the bottom

Comment: When I enter `http://www.shareyourrepair.com/2012/08/how-to-put-patch-on-inner-tube.html&_esc‌​aped_fragment_=?view=flipcard` into my browser it gets a page not found error still and in the log it says it trying to open `ShareYourRepair.com/2012/08/how-to-put-patch-on-inner-tube.html&_esc%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Baped_fragment_=?view=flipcard`

Comment: You must clear your browser cache. Then click on [this link](http://www.shareyourrepair.com/2012/08/how-to-put-patch-on-inner-tube.html&_escaped_fragment_=?view=flipcard)

Comment: You are correct, it is working, THANK YOU SO MUCH, I really mean that--this has been a huge burden on me.  I really appreciate it.